# SQL Server 2008 Sync - How to reinsert conflicting pk rows with new primary key

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, synchronization

Can someone point me in the right direction for handling a PK conflict error in c# .net using Sync Framework.

I am trying to sync between sql server 2008 and local data cache database (.sdf) and would like to keep BOTH rows that are conflicting in both server and client and NOT allow either the server or client win?

I get a pk conflict error when I insert a new row into both the server and client that have the same PK id.

Any suggestions would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: How close to a working solution are you ? Have you considered using the Microsoft Sync Framework. This has a nice conflict resolution system in it.

Comment: I am using the Sync Framework however for a PK conflict (ClientInsertServerInsert) there are no options to specify accept both rows into both tables (as far as I can tell).

Comment: When you have a two sided conflict you either need to write a log for reconciliation ; or change the key with a force write

Comment: I have fixed this problem now by using a GUID for a PK instead of a auto-incrementing int.  This guarantees that each row inserted by the server or any client will be unique.  I know there are some disadvantages such as additional storage space and time it takes to search but this is something I am willing to live with (and I will filter the data that the client gets which will help to improve performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by using a GUID for the PK instead of a auto-incrementing int.

This guarantees that each row inserted by the server or any client will be unique and works very well.

There are some disadvantages such as additional storage space and time it takes to search etc but this is something I am willing to live with (and I will filter the data that the client gets which will help to improve performance).

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

General principle for this type of problem is to have a column for a natural key. The idea is that  the primary key uniquely identifies a row in a table, while  the natural key uniquely identifies an object that the row describes. In case of a conflict, let the server win and insert a new row on the client side. New PK will be issued, but the natural key stays the same. Later it is easy to find those rows by ordering by the natural key.